# Information Architecture - Navigation - Accessibility

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, accessibility, experience, click

Recently I have worked on a dashboard(Web).
It is a web enterprise product with a lot of data in each view with 20+ views.
To make navigation simpler we made a **change view** text button with blue color to say that it is clickable and once the user clicks on this user gets a drop down of different Views.
In Breadcrumb we show which view is selected example: Overview is selected in the view dropdown so that is shown in breadcrumbs.

***(This drop-down comes in left side of the dashboard)***

[image]

To improve Ux on this instead of click we made it on hover, So whenever the user hovers on change view User gets a drop down of the list of views that user can change.

But by the time we thought the problem is solved, We saw that there were not enough clicks happening on that widget.

What do you think can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a button instead of a textlink to signal the user that its clickable.
If your users aren't clicking right now because they dont know its clickable this will solve it, if not there may be other reasons they don't click.

Ps.: if you are against buttons for some reason, adding an icon might also work, although not as good as a button but enough to draw attention to that action.[image]

Comment: can you please draw some rough wireframe for it .

Comment: Edited to my post.

Comment: yes,will give it a try